# Primefaces LineChart: Cannot change DateAxis format

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
model.getAxis(AxisType.X).setTickFormat("%H:%#M:%S");
DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis("Time");
model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, dateAxis);
```

1. Even I set my tick format as above it renders the following x axis labels (adds month info unexpectedly):

[image]

To render month info is not desired situation by my clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new Axis and setting it as the X axis after setting the tick format for what becomes the old `Axis` so those changes will be wiped out.

Try either of the following code snippets.

```
LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis("Time");
model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, dateAxis);
model.getAxis(AxisType.X).setTickFormat("%H:%#M:%S");
```

Or

```
LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis("Time");
datAxis.setTickFormat("%H:%#M:%S");
model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, dateAxis);
```